# Separate tagged word from larger string in python?

Tags: python

I have string of unknown length where tagged words are separated by comma's .I want to get those individual words or strings. I already know that we could use first **python.replace(',',' ')** to replace , with space and then use **python.split()** to separate words but this will fail in the case where tagged word consist of multiple words, for eg.  *"algebra , theory of computation , operating system , cars"*
How to handle this case in python.
It is not given that words will always be separated by " . " (space+comma+space)
Output I am expecting is ["algebra","theory of computation","operating system","cars"]

Comment: What is the actual output you expect here?

Comment: Why can't you just split on the comma?

Comment: Please write the code you have tried to reach but got error, and write your expected output and errors if got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the same using split()

```
strr="qweweqw,qweqwrqwr,were,we  rwer,ffd xcv"

print(strr.split(','))
```

output

```
['qweweqw', 'qweqwrqwr', 'were', 'we  rwer', 'ffd xcv']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom separator in split() function by providing it as an argument. In your case: `.split(' , ')`

Comment: it is not given that words will always be separated by " , "

Comment: An example you provided consists only of ' , ' separators. What else do you need to handle?

Comment: I want to get string separated by two comma's .there can be a case where comma separating two words is not followed by space for eg. "algebra,theory of computation , operating system ,cars"

Comment: If you have double commas in your string, replace them first using `.replace(',,',',')`. Then do the split by `.split(',')`. Then strip the output strings of leading and trailing spaces using `.strip()`. Giving your string is a variable named `strr`, a one-liner could look like this: `[x.strip() for x in strr.replace(',,',',').split(',')]`